# How to set the VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY in Saleor eCommerce Platform?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, saleor

`Saleor Django` eCommerce Platform. I have just started setting up and learning `Saleor` and I am stuck setting the `VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY`. I get the following error (Could not fetch tax rates. Make sure you have supplied a valid API Access Key. Check the server logs for more information about this error.). I have registered for a key `API` at `VatLayer` https://vatlayer.com/

I have set the key "this key is an example" in the common.env file as `VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY=2bb221d7fbce9fd274791959e120999d`.

Is this the correct location to set the key or should it be in the `saleor/settings.py` file and are there additional settings I need to apply to enable `VatLayer`?

Answer (score 0):

To successfully fetch tax rates for Saleor eCommerce Platform using your own `VATLAYER_API_KEY` supplied by https://vatlayer.com/.

Edit the `saleor/settings.py` file, search for `VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY`, and change:

```
VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY")
```

to:

```
VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("VATLAYER_ACCESS_KEY", "add_my_vat_layer_access_key_here")
```

and save.